# WindowsPhone 8 (phonegap) and AngularJs - $routeProvider not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

My mind is gone. I don't know what is the problem for my code.

hmm, I will explain for that.

File details :

Cordova 2.9.1 version

angularjs 1.2.13 version ( also used all version with the latest (1.2.16) version)

and i have used Windows Phone 8 App

Here is my code

App.js

```
'use strict';
window.myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.mobile-navigate', 'ngMobile',
    'myApp.Registermdl',
   'myApp.login', 'myApp.CreateUsermdl', 'myApp.viewMap', 'myApp.createMap',
'myApp.logout', 'ngProgress', 'ngCookies','ngRoute'])


myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(http?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);

    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'index.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/login', { templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/home', { templateUrl: 'app/home/home.htm', controller: 'HomeCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/createuser', { templateUrl: 'app/CreateUser/createUser.html', controller: 'CreateUserCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/signup', { templateUrl: 'app/register/register.html', controller: 'RegisterCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/logout', { templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html', controller: 'LogoutCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/view-map', { templateUrl: 'app/ViewMap/viewmap.html', controller: 'ViewMapCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/create-map', { templateUrl: 'app/CreateMapAddress/create-mapaddress.html', controller: 'CreateMapAddressCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

myApp.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$route', '$cookieStore', '$cookies',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route, $cookieStore, $cookies) {
        if ($cookieStore.get('userEmail') == undefined) {
            $rootScope.IsLogin = false;
            $rootScope.IsLogout = true;
            $rootScope.IsAdmin = false;
            $rootScope.userName = "";
            $scope.$apply();
            if ($location.$$path == "/signup") {
                $location.$$path = "/signup";
                $route.reload();
                return false;
            }
            $location.$$path = "/login";
            $route.reload();
            alert("goos Start5");
            return false;
        }
        $rootScope.IsAdmin = false;
        if ($cookieStore.get('userRole') == "Admin") {
            $rootScope.IsAdmin = true;
        }
        $rootScope.IsLogin = true;
        $rootScope.IsLogout = false;
        $rootScope.userName = $cookieStore.get('userEmail');
        $route.reload();

    }]);
//var hostname = 'qbsnewsvr/CollegeApp';
var hostname = 'localhost:54938/';
var rootUrl = 'http://' + hostname;
```

and index page (main page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Use the .min version of bootstrap files in production -->
    <!-- Use the following if you want to use responsive design -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/bootstrap-custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/toastr.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Scripts begins-->

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
    <link href="css/MSDList.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- The following tag is in place of ng-view to use the angular mobile view navigation framework
            https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav
        -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">College App</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/home">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#/home">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/home">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div ng-show="IsLogin">
                    <p class="navbar-text welocome-aliginment">Welcome <a href="#" class="wecome-text" id="welcomeName">{{userName}}</a></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#/login" ng-show="IsLogout">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/signup" ng-show="IsLogout">SignUp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/createuser" ng-show="IsLogin && IsAdmin">Create New User</a></li>
                    <li class="active" ng-show="IsLogin"><a href="#/view-map">View Map</a></li>
                    <!-- <li class="active" ng-show="IsLogin"><a href="#/create-map">Create Map</a></li>-->
                    <li class="active" ng-show="IsLogin"><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
    <!-- Comment out the following 2 lines to test on the browser-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- In production use min versions -->
    <script src="js/q.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/jx.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/mobile-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <!-- 3rd party libraries -->
    <script src="js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngProgress/ngProgress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/MSDList.js"></script>

    <!-- app js -->
    <!-- <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key=AIzaSyBbd_4N1j8WIoRJ0trcrqGLlo0a6T_e-bA"></script>-->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;ver=3.5.1"></script>-->

    <!-- <script src="lib/Clusterer2.js"></script>-->
    <!-- controller  -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="app/register/register.js"></script>
    <script src="app/CreateUser/createUser.js"></script>
    <script src="app/login/login.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ViewMap/viewmap.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Login/logout.js"></script>
    <script src="app/CreateMapAddress/create-mapaddress.js"></script>
    <!-- logger -->
    <script src="js/logger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is working good on all browser. But only not worked in Emulator. I have tried soooooo many ways.

And i got some answers from Stack overflow

There have config this line

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(http?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
```

but i already did this.  Everything is okay. But the `$routeProvider` is not working in emulator.(that means the page does not redirect to index page).

I don't know. it is a version problem or any conflict problem, etc...

### Any One Help Me Please

Comment: what you see on emulator when you run your app?

Comment: @HardikThakkar A blank screen and if i click any menu(like login), It's does not gone that screen.

Comment: @HardikThakkar and also this same code is working another application. i also check every single line and every files. but no luck

Comment: "this same code is working another application" -> Is this another application is working fine on Windows phone? Have to tested this on IE?

Comment: ajoslin.mobile-navigate is not fully supported with IE/Windows Mobile. You need to modify CSS of it to support IE. I have a copy of it if you would like to give it a try. Also there are some minor tweeking in js too to make this module work on windows phone browser.

Comment: But I have used the same js in another project, There have it is working. Please can you give any examble for that?

Comment: Is this another project working fine on Windows Emulator?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51667/discussion-between-hardik-thakkar-and-user256103)

Comment: It might also be due to fact,you might not have set app.js properties to copy always.If this was not set the file wouldnt have been include during compilation.Just check this property.This is just a suggestion

Answer (score 2):

To fix angularjs route for window mobile app add "ms-appx" for unsafe:ms-appx://.

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ms-appx):/)
```